# Combination of multiple fields unique in mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an model:

```
let MySchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated: {
    type: Date
  },
  user_id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true
  },
  material_id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "Material",
    required: true
  },
  data: { }
});
```

How to set combinations of `user_id` and `material_id` unique, but I need unique only in combination of both this fields not like just add `unique: true` for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have found the answer:

```
MySchema.index({ user_id: 1, material_id: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

It will create the index with combination of two fields and you won't be able to create new document in mongoDB with same two indexes but you can create documents if some of indexes is not the same as saved in DB already.
That's exactly what I was looking for.